# Solve $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{2x-2}{(x^3-x)^2}$ without L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

Find limit without L'Hôpital's rule: $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{2x-2}{(x^3-x)^2}$

I'm learning limits and I'm stuck with this example. So far, I tried modify denominator but I have no luck with it.

Comment: The limit doesn't exist since as $x\to 1^+$ we have $\frac{2x-2}{(x^3-x)^2}\to +\infty$. While $x\to 1^{-}$ implies $\frac{2x-2}{(x^3-x)^2}\to -\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{2x-2}{(x^3-x)^2}=\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{2(x-1)}{x^2(x^2-1)^2}=\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{2(x-1)}{x^2(x-1)^2(x+1)^2}$$

Therefore $\lim\limits_{x \to 1^+} \frac{2}{x^2(x-1)(x+1)^2}=+\infty$

and $\lim\limits_{x \to 1^-} \frac{2}{x^2(x-1)(x+1)^2}=-\infty$

Answer (score 3):

HINT : factor the polynom : $x^3-x = x(x+1)(x-1)$

Comment: answer should be $+\infty$ or $-\infty$